# Importing the es6-promise polyfill into Vue.js

Tags: javascript, android, es6-promise, vuejs2, polyfills

I am having problems loading a Vue component containing axios in older version of Android. After some research it pointed towards the browser not supporting Promises, hence the polyfill.

I have installed and imported the polyfill but still having problems.

```
import Promise from 'es6-promise';
```

Is the above correct? Or is there a further problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have following line on top of my main.js:

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill()
```

other variant of it's use you can see in vue-hackernews-2.0 [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/cd8c75002957bb029b8cd1938eccda7c09edfcf4/src/client-entry.js):

```
import 'es6-promise/auto'
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tested and the issue seemed to be not complying for production with gulp. It's good to know this though.